# C++ initializing vector with iterators

Tags: c++, string, vector, ifstream, stringstream

I am attempting to read a file of unsigned characters into a vector. My slightly roundabout way of doing this is by creating an input file stream, reading that data into a stringstream, and initializing a vector using the contents of the stringstream. There is probably a much better way to do this, and my existing code causes a segmentation fault using certain files.

```
string file_name = "output/comp" + to_string(start_id) + ".xml";

if( !file_exists(file_name))
{
    cout << "File could not be found." << endl;
    return 0;
}

ifstream ifs(file_name);
stringstream ss;
ss << ifs.rdbuf();
ss >> noskipws;

vector<unsigned char> raw_data(ss.str().begin(), ss.str().end());
```

I have included all the necessary headers and `using` declarations, and `file_exists()` returns a boolean value indicating whether or not the file exists.

My question is this: Why is the above code incorrect, and what is the best method for correctly accomplishing the same objective?

Comment: Probably need to add `binary` to the file open mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::stringstream::str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) returns a `std::string`. That is, it's a temporary string.

So `ss.str().begin()` returns the beginning iterator for a temporary string, and `ss.str().end()` returns the ending iterator of a *different* temporary string, because both `ss.str()` calls are returning *different* temporary strings. You can't mix iterators between different objects!

To fix this, use one string:

```
std::string str = ss.str();
```

And now just pass `str.begin()` and `str.end()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with

```
vector<unsigned char> raw_data(ss.str().begin(), ss.str().end());
```

is that `str()` returns a temporary string.  This means the `string` you use for `begin` is not the same `string` you use for `end`.  Since the iterators do not refer to the same `string` you cannot use them together.

Instead of using a `strignstream` we can read the file directly into the vector using `istream_iterator`s like

```
std::ifstream ifs(file_name);
std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> start(ifs), end;
std::vector<unsigned char> raw_data(start, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not exactly sure why that would cause a segfault, perhaps something in string stream, but with c++11 it's very easy to read a file into a string once you have any istream derivative:

```
std::string readFileAsString(std::istream& stream)
{
     return std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}
```

*edit* sorry, I forgot you wanted the bytes at the end

```
return std::vector<char>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```